# Combining OSMnx Multipolygons

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, osmnx

### What are best practices in generating a union of Multipolygons acquired as a group using [OSMnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx)'s [gdf_from_places()](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.gdf_from_places)?

In  [gboeing](https://github.com/gboeing)'s [02-example-osm-to-shapefile.ipynb](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/02-example-osm-to-shapefile.ipynb) example, multiple shapefiles are downloaded from OSM to a geodataframe using the gdf_from_places() method. The geometry is stored as Multipolygons in a Geopanda's dataframe with each row representing a place.

```
# you can pass multiple queries with mixed types (dicts and strings)
mx_gt_tx = ox.gdf_from_places(queries=[{'country':'Mexico'}, 'Guatemala', {'state':'Texas'}])
mx_gt_tx = ox.project_gdf(mx_gt_tx)
fig, ax = ox.plot_shape(mx_gt_tx)
```

[image: osmnx gdf_from_places example]

In regards to the question, I've experimented with using Geopanda's [GeoSeries.unary_union](http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html#GeoSeries.unary_union) but wanted to know how others were accomplishing this programmatically in Python.

### Current Process 2018

This method uses the [Shapely function of unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) (it would otherwise be mx_gt_tx["geometry"].unary_union through Geopandas as pointed out by @joris comment.

```
queries = [{'country':'Mexico'}, 'Guatemala', {'state':'Texas'}]

# buffer_dist is in meters
mx_gt_tx = ox.gdf_from_places(queries, gdf_name='region_mx_gt_tx')
mx_gt_tx
```

[image: Imgur]

```
# project the geometry to the appropriate UTM zone then plot it
mx_gt_tx = ox.project_gdf(mx_gt_tx)
fig, ax = ox.plot_shape(mx_gt_tx)
```

[image: Imgur]

```
# unary union through Geopandas
region_mx_gt_tx = gpd.GeoSeries(unary_union(mx_gt_tx["geometry"]))
region_mx_gt_tx.plot(color = 'blue')
plt.show()
print(region_mx_gt_tx )
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: It appears that the resulting osmnx gdf does not store the shapes as Multipolygons, but Polygons.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is the result you get from `unary_union` not what you want?

Comment: @joris The result is what I am looking for, though I do not know if this is the 'best practice' way to get that result. I asked the question looking for other points of view on methods to create the union.

Comment: I think this is certainly seen as best practice (I don't know any better way). Note that you didn't use the GeoSeries.unary_union method, but the shapely function (it would otherwise be `mx_gt_tx["geometry"].unary_union` instead of `unary_union(mx_gt_tx["geometry"])`), but both are fine (and the one is using the other under the hood)

Comment: @joris Thanks for the clarification and pointing that out! Definitely an artifact left over from trying a variety of methods to get a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import osmnx as ox
gdf = ox.gdf_from_places(queries=[{'country':'Mexico'}, 'Guatemala', {'state':'Texas'}])
unified = gdf.unary_union
```